# robot_upstart: could not open port /dev/ttyUSB0

Tags: ros, permission, robot-upstart

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I use turtlebot roomba with indigo version.
I try to use `robot_upstart` package to run `turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch` from an upstrat:

```
rosrun robot_upstart install --job turtlebot --interface wlan0 --user myuser --setup /home/myuser/turtlebot/devel/setup.bash --rosdistro indigo --master http://192.168.1.2:11311 --logdir /home/myuser/.ros/log turtlebot_bringup/launch/minimal.launch
```

All work properly except serial connection:

```
Failed to open port /dev/ttyUSB0. Error: could not open port /dev/ttyUSB0: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/ttyUSB0' Please make sure the Create cable is plugged into the computer.
```

'myuser' is in the 'dialout' group. If I start `roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch` in a terminal it works.

If I start  `sudo service turtlebot start` it doesn't work.

If I manually change port permission `sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSB0` service start without errors.

Anyone having an idea what could be wrong?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207892/robot_upstart:-could-not-open-port-/dev/ttyusb0/) by [dennn66](https://answers.ros.org/users/22275/dennn66/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-04-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) on 2015-11-03**:
hi dennn666, did you figure this issue out? Also do you know how to determine the Network interface to bring ROS up with, which is **wlan0** in your case. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is some additional clarification for what @Rasoul wrote.

> 'myuser' is in the 'dialout' group.

That is normally all that is required, but `robot_upstart` works a bit different. From the [robot_upstart 0.2.0 documentation » The install script - permissions](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/robot_upstart/html/install.html#permissions):

> It’s important to understand how permissions work robot_upstart:

> 1. The upstart job invokes its `jobname-start` bash script as root.

> 1. The script sets up environment variables, and then uses setuidgid to execute roslaunch as an unprivileged user. This is by default the user who ran the install script, but it can also be specified explicitly via a flag.

> 1. **The roslaunch which executes does not have its user’s group memberships**. This means that it will **not have access to serial ports with the `dialout` group**, or locations in /var/log owned by root, etc. Any filesystem resources needed by your ROS nodes should be chowned to the same unprivileged user which will run ROS, or should set to world readable/writeable, for example using udev.

So `jobname-start` starts out as user `root`, but then quickly drops all privileges and continues as a regular user (that is not a member of the `dialout` group). That is why some more configuration is required.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [borgcons](https://answers.ros.org/users/32279/borgcons/) on 2017-12-06**:
Hi What user would that be? the script uses setuidgid and sets to the user myuser, which is in the dialout group. When I do the same thing in my case and look at the processes run in htop the user is myuser. So how can the process run as myuser but not have the permissions of myuser?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In order to solve the problem, perform the following steps:

> sudo gedit
> /etc/udev/rules.d/my-usbaccess.rules

Write the following into the file

> KERNEL=="ttyUSB0", MODE="0666"
> into the file

Save the file and reboot.

---

Originally posted by [Rasoul](https://answers.ros.org/users/1477/rasoul/) with karma: 115 on 2015-09-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Waron](https://answers.ros.org/users/25742/waron/) on 2016-01-27**:
Is it possible for udev rules in /lib/udev/rules.d/ to override rules you create in /etc/udev/rules.d/ ?